# How to safely purge in Varnish if backend is sick without losing content

Tags: varnish, purge

If the backend is sick, what is the preferable way to ensure that stale content can be retrieved from the backend when a PURGE request is made?

When a PURGE request is made, whether or not the backend is sick, by default the content will be eliminated from the Varnish cache and if the backend is down, a 503 page would be served to the user until the backend comes back online to serve a new version of the content. I'd like to be able to at least serve up a stale version of the content if a new version could not be retrieved from the backend.

Is this possible without installing the [Softpurge Varnish Mod](https://github.com/lkarsten/libvmod-softpurge)?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Any Varnish 3.0 purge command will set the object TTL so it is seen as expired, and the expiry thread will reclaim the memory within seconds/milliseconds.

The softpurge VMOD does mostly what purge does, but in addition recomputes the grace value so even if it is expired it is not a candidate for eviction by the expiry thread.